# Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer Unresponsive

Tags: visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction here.

I've recently started using Visual Studio 2012. The project I'm working on was originally in VS2010. Source control is managed via TFS 2010.

The issue I'm having is that the server explorer becomes unrepsonsive when the projecs in my solution load and stays that way. I can't expand any of the server connections. Clicking on a connection does nothing. All I see is the blue circle of infinite frustration.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2 and Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 (30319.01).

The SQL servers in my connections are msotly SQL 2008 with one or two SQL 2005 servers.

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
The problem seems to be connected to clicking on pending changes in the team explorer window. If I don't do that then all is fine and I can expand the server explorer connections.

Comment: Why was the unresponsive tag removed? The problem still persists and causes the server explorer window to become, you guessed it, UNRESPONSIVE.